# Stackoverflow being cause with simple code

Tags: java, recursion, constructor, jvm, stack-overflow

My code is very simple, and I'm trying to learn java/android studio, I can't figure out why am I getting a stackoverflow with this:

```
public class Main {

    private String main_name = "dummy_string";
    private String name1 = "name1";
    private String name2 = "name2";
    private String name3 = "name3";

    private final Main[] Drinks={
        new Main(name1),
        new Main(name2),
        new Main(name3)
    };

    public Main(){}

    private Main(String name_value){
        this.main_name = name_value;
    }

    public  void get_value(int index){
        System.out.println(this.Drinks[index]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main_obj = new Main();
        main_obj.get_value(0);
        main_obj.get_value(1);
        main_obj.get_value(2);
   }  
}
```

Even though I have made no recursive calls, stackoverflow is occuring.

Comment: `Drinks` array is the problem. When you create `Main` object you create also an array which has 3 `Main` objects and so on recursively...

Comment: You have made recursive calls: when you construct a Main, it creates an array populated with 3 new Main instances, so the Main constructor is called 3 additional times, which constructs 9 more Main instances, etc. etc.

Comment: Side note: variables and mathods start with a lwoercase letter, and are camelCased. They never contain an underscore.

Comment: but, that's really a convention, isn't it? I like underscores so I kept them,.... does it cause any problem down the road?

Comment: If you share stacktrace, you will see recursion in [<init> method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is your problem:

```
private final Main[] Drinks={
    new Main(name1),
    new Main(name2),
    new Main(name3)
};
```

You're creating `Main` class with `Drinks` array in it, that contains instances of `Main` each of which must have `Drinks` array and so on.

Comment: but, isn't instantiating a class inside the same class allowed in java?

Comment: @juztcode It does allow but in doing so will result in your program going into a recursive death spiral. For more check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607757/object-of-the-class-as-instance-variable-inside-the-class?lq=1#answer-13608203